# Sprite Kit Coordinates Reversed order

Tags: sprite-kit

I haven't had this problem before, so I'm wondering if it's a bug.

```
NSLog(@"%f %f", self.frame.size.height, self.frame.size.width);
```

is giving me

```
768.000000 1024.000000
```

And my app is only set to allow portrait mode. What???

Comment: The orientation of the device and the dimensions of the scene are independent unless you set the scene's scale mode appropriately.

Comment: @0x141E my viewcontroller.m has `scene.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleModeAspectFill;`, is this incorrect?

Comment: is your scene being loaded form an `sks` file, you can change the size in the file.

Comment: I changed the sks dimensions and it didn't change anything. I tried all the scale modes.

Comment: I think this might have something to do with screen size not updating in time. This link might help. http://www.ymc.ch/en/ios-7-sprite-kit-setting-up-correct-scene-dimensions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must be using SpriteKit. You need to make sure to resize the screen by using `self.size = self.frame.size;` inside your `initWithSize:(CGSize)size` method of the class you're using (the default would be gameScene).

Essentially:

```
-(id)initWithSize:(CGSize)size {    
if (self = [super initWithSize:size]) {
    /* Setup your scene here */

    self.size = self.frame.size;

    // Your code here

    };
return self;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For Xcode 6 in GameScene.m put this:

```
-(void)didMoveToView:(SKView *)view {

 /* Setup your scene here */

    self.size = self.view.frame.size;


}
```